# To find Hourly data when data is for 15 mins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I have a data for 15 mins. I want to find total parts produced for each one hour in a day for the given date.

TotalPartsProduced in one hour = (starting of one hour) - (end of one hour)
10 AM - 11 AM  =   44086 -   42793
10 AM - 11 AM  =     1293

My Data :

```
DateTime                     TotalPartsProduced
 --------------------------------------------------
2023-04-28 10:11:48.860        42793
2023-04-28 10:26:48.737        43259
2023-04-28 10:41:48.667        43674
2023-04-28 10:56:48.427        44086

2023-04-28 11:11:49.043        44501
2023-04-28 11:26:48.787        44501
2023-04-28 11:41:49.020        44548

2023-04-28 17:02:23.363        50376
2023-04-28 17:17:23.557        50867
2023-04-28 17:32:23.690        50995
2023-04-28 17:47:23.613        50995
```

Expected results:

```
TIME              TotalPartsProduced/Hour
-----------------------------------------------
10AM-11AM                 1293
11AM-12PM                 47
```

Please guide how can I achieve this  by giving a specific date in where condition.

Comment: Did either of the answers below address your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case when `select distinct` could come handy, along with `first_value`:

```
select distinct dt_hour, 
      first_value(TotalPartsProduced) over(partition by dt_hour order by dt desc)
    - first_value(TotalPartsProduced) over(partition by dt_hour order by dt     ) TotalPartsProduced
from (
    select t.*, 
        datetimefromparts(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt), datepart(hour, dt), 0, 0, 0) dt_hour
    from mytable t
    where dt >= '2023-04-28' and dt < '2023-04-29'
) t
```

The subquery is just there to perform the hour truncation of the timestamp (note that I renamed column `DateTime` to `dt`, so it does not clash with the corresponding SQL keyword).

Then, the outer query uses `first_value` to retrieve the first and last value of each timeslot; unfortunately there is no aggregate counterpart for this window function, so the last step is `distinct`.

I hardcoded the date filtering part; you can pass a parameter instead, if that's what you want.

| dt_hour | TotalPartsProduced |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-28 10:00:00.000 | 1293 |
| 2023-04-28 11:00:00.000 | 47 |
| 2023-04-28 17:00:00.000 | 619 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JIX0LhRa)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  the TotalPartsProduced always increasing per hour, then you could simply use the `min()` and `max()`, if not the case then @GMB's answer is the solution :

```
select CAST(DateTime as date) as 'Date', DATEPART(hour,DateTime) as 'Time', max(TotalPartsProduced) - min(TotalPartsProduced) as 'TotalPartsProduced/hour'
from mytable
GROUP BY CAST(DateTime as date), DATEPART(hour,DateTime)
```

Result :

```
Date        Time    TotalPartsProduced/hour
2023-04-28  10      1293
2023-04-28  11      47
2023-04-28  17      619
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TieIFEvl)

Comment: Right, but this assumes that `TotalPartsProduced` always increases, which might or might not be a valid assumption.